# Rails <script> tag in <head> having random string in "type" attribute and therefore not loading JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6, sprockets, rails-sprockets

In my Ruby on Rails website, script tags in head get assigned random string in `type` attribute. It only happens on a single page though. All other pages are fine and the correct `type="text/javascript"` is used. Therefore, on that page scripts aren't being loaded and I have to fix it.

It only happens in production.

Noticed that all scripts have exactly the same string prepended before `text/javascript` and it changes on each reload.

Absolutely have no idea where to even start. Maybe you could help out?

[image: Screenshot of script tag in head from DevTools]

Comment: Did you check your `javascript_include_tag` or `javascript_pack_tag` lines in your view code? Maybe one of them is adding something special?

Comment: There is only one `javascript_include_tag`. It's the same for all pages, nothing page-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you figured this out... we noticed this happens when you are using Cloudflare and have enabled their Rocket Loader feature.